# Proof of Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: proof-verification, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

This proof was released this year:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00533

Where is the mistake? I just found it and was wondering how obviously wrong it is.

Comment: Already the very first sentence of the introduction has two mistakes in "every nontirivial zeros"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Haha, I mean mathematical mistakes.

Comment: Nine pages certainly does not induce confidence 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *proof* of lemma 2.1 (the first thing the author proves at all) is false (though I didn't check if the *claim* of the lemma is possibly correct for other reasons):

Let $R_n(s):= \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^{s}}$. This $R$ has sufficiently similar properties as the series remainder term, at least as far as they were used in the alleged proof:
First of all, $$\tag1\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n(s)=0.$$
Next, $$R_n(s)-R_{n-1}(s)=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^{s}}-\frac{1-(-1)^n}{(n-1)^{s}}=\begin{cases}-\frac{2}{(n-1)^s}&n\text{ odd}\\\hphantom{-}\frac2{n^s}&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$ and 
$$R_n(s)-R_{n+1}(s)=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^{s}}-\frac{1-(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{s}}=\begin{cases}-\frac{2}{(n+1)^s}&n\text{ odd}\\\hphantom{-}\frac2{n^s}&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$
so that
$$\frac{R_n(s)-R_{n-1}(s)}{R_n(s)-R_{n+1}(s)}=\begin{cases}\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)^s&n\text{ odd}\\1&n\text{ even} \end{cases}$$
and $$\tag2 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{R_n(s)-R_{n-1}(s)}{R_n(s)-R_{n+1}(s)}=1.$$
It appears that the author thinks that $(1)$ and $(2)$ (or maybe even $(2)$ alone) imply
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-R_{n-1}(s)}{R_n(s)}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-R_{n+1}(s)}{R_n(s)}=1.$$
However, with $R$ as defined by me, these limits do not even exist.

Comment: Ha, thanks. What an odd thing to say.