# Proof (claimed) for Riemann hypothesis on ArXiv

Tags: soft-question, riemann-hypothesis

Has anyone noticed the paper [On the zeros of the zeta function and eigenvalue problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01555) by M. R. Pistorius, available on ArXiv?

The author claims a proof of RH, and also a growth condition on the zeros.
It was posted two weeks ago, and I expected it would have been shot down by now. Has there been any discussion or attempt at verification of this preprint?

Comment: I actually would be interested to know where is the flaw of this proof and what they tried to prove.

Comment: I do not understand the close votes on this question. It is clear to me what this question is asking: "Has anyone evaluated the veracity of this paper?" and (implicitly) "If so, is it correct? If not, what are the flaws?" I also disagree that the question is off-topic. On MO, discussing the validity of recently announced results is discouraged, but I don't know of any similar policy on MSE.

Comment: fwiw, I've checked Lemma 3

Comment: A four page proof would be very impressive

Comment: @AlexR. Is equation $9$ where they say $v_\psi(\pi/2,t)$. That means replace $x=\pi/2$ which gets rid of the cosine, and $\mu=t$.

Comment: Lemma 3 is a claim about (3) for a very general class of functions $p,q,r$. But the proof relies on a specific choice of $p,q,r$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It is true that Lemma 3 is somewhat ill-formulated. It is not meant as a statement for a general class of functions p,q,r, but should be read as $v_b(\frac12\pi, \mu) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mu^2$ is real.

Comment: There's some discussion in French here: http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1309001,1309477, where user YvesM claimes to have found errors: "la condition 5,b ne garantie pas v(1)=0 et l'équation différentielle sur v est fausse."

Comment: I am puzzled by this being closed, and also by the negative votes. The "missing content" criticism just misses the point of the question. I deliberately put this on MSE rather than MO for precisely the reason described in @AlexWertheim's comment.

Comment: @HansLundmark Now I'm even more lost. Why would $v(1)$ play any particular role?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Don't ask me, I'm only quoting...

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/ and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/ for meta discussion on such questions

Comment: Only four pages and it doesn't look like anything advanced or esoteric.  Some authors would begin with a 40-page synopsis of earlier research before starting the 80-page proof.

Comment: Where exactly is the Sturm-Louville equation the author claims that $\Xi$ or $\Psi$ satisfies?

Comment: I'm very surprised, honestly. I was convinced that both this site and MO discourage posing "is this paper correct?" kind of questions. Judging from the votes, apparently I was very wrong.

Comment: @Wojowu Perhaps you aren't, it's just that this is kind of surprising...

Comment: Among other things, it is odd that the author stops to say that the sum of the inverse $1+\epsilon$ powers of absolute values converges, since that has been known since Hadamard's work on products, about 120 years ago...

Comment: @Wojowu Same here (except that I am positive that you are not wrong on this).

Comment: I'm stunned that there are no acknowledgements of any kind. The author is at a top-flight institution (but appears to work in financial mathematics) and didn't run this by _anyone_?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had a go reading through the paper and I think I found the error. The main argument in the paper can be summarized as follows:

> The Riemann $\Xi$-function $\Xi(t) = \xi\left(\frac{1}{2} + it\right)$ satisfy $\Xi(t) = \Xi(0)\nu_t(\pi/2)$ where $$\nu_t(x) = \int_0^\infty \cos(t(y+\cos(x))\Phi(y){\rm d}y$$ and $\Phi$ is related to the Jacobi $\theta$-function. This is a result by Riemann and holds true. The author then notes that when $t$ is such that $\Xi(t) = 0$ then $\nu_t(x)$ satisfy the Sturm–Liouville (SL) problem 
>   $$\left(\frac{\nu_t'(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)' + t^2\sin(x)\nu_t(x) = 0,~~~\nu_t'(0) = 0,~~~\nu_t(\pi/2) = 0$$
>   This is also true. The proof is completed by appealing to a theorem that says that this problem only has real eigenvalues. If this holds then it follows that $\Xi(t) = 0\implies t\in\mathbb{R}$ which is the Riemann hypotesis.

The error is in the last step. It is indeed true that a *regular* [SL problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) only has real eigenvalues, however this is not a regular SL problem as $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ has a pole at $x=0$. In this case there is no guarantee that the eigenvalues have to be real and we can show this explicitly with a simple counter-example: the function $\nu_t(x) = \sin(t\cos(x))$ satisfy the SL problem above for any complex number $t$.

---

Given how much interest this question has generated, which I take to mean that many people thought (or perhaps just hoped) this was a potentially viable proof, I think it’s useful to talk a bit about why it *had* to be wrong. Personally I have only been in academia for $\sim 10$ years, but I have already managed to see $\sim 50$ papers$^1$ like this where a major result is proven in a few pages using elementary methods. This is just another one. One soon learns that papers like this are *never* correct and the reason is often this: if it could have been solved this way then it would have been solved this way many many years ago - the techniques used are just too simple. As for some useful pointers for how to judge for yourself if a paper like this has the potential for being correct I reccommend Scott Aaronsons ["*Ten Signs a Claimed Mathematical Breakthrough is Wrong*"](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=304).

$^1$ For some examples see the MSE questions [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542507/proof-of-riemann-hypothesis?rq=1), [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406367/this-is-a-possible-proof-of-the-riemann-hypothesis?rq=1), [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775873/riemann-hypothesis-proof-legit?rq=1)

Comment: he use theorem 2 to prove that eigenvalues are real i think

Comment: @Hamza Either some assumptions of that theorem is not satisfied or the theorem as phrased is not correct. The standard proof that the eigenvalues of $[p(x)y'(x)]' = \lambda r(x) y(x)$ are real does not apply when $p(x)$ has a pole. A quick calculation gives  
$$\left(p(x)[\overline{y} y' - \overline{y}'y]\right)_a^b = (\lambda - \overline{\lambda}) \int_a^br(x) |y(x)|^2{\rm d}x$$
If $p(a),p(b)$ are finite then the BC imply that the left hand side vanish and $\lambda$ is real. However when $p(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ this is not the case (the left hand side becomes a $0\cdot \infty$ limit).

Comment: Excellent counter-example; cf. edit in my post.

Comment: While I consider the question as completely off-topic I still upvoted this not only but also for the last paragraph. Of note in that context, the paper was posted in the General Mathematics section on arXiv.

Comment: I forget the source, but  I once read that a certain 19th-century mathematician  had a form-letter reply for answering amateurs'  submissions to him of attempts to prove Fermat's Last Theorem: "Thank you. You have an error on page ----, line ----."

Comment: @quid why is the question off-topic?

Comment: "never correct" you probably mean rarely correct. An elementary proof of prime number theorem, which some people consider to be a major result, was found after an analytic proof (if there was an elementary proof, why didn't they discover it before?).

Comment: @gentbent because  questions asking in general terms about the merits of a  paper are not in the scope of the site, especially not when they are of this form.

Comment: @quid is there a claim in FAQ or help center to that effect?

Comment: @gentbent it's covered by "too broad". It also came up on meta at times see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/proof-verification-of-open-problems

Comment: @gentbent No I really mean never correct. Elementary here doesn't mean "non analytic", it means *elementary* in the colloquial sense! The proof of the PNT would of course not fall into this category.

Answer (score 22):

I'll try to summarize my understanding of the manuscript ([v2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01555v2.pdf)). I was unable to find any issue with the proof (**Edit:** see [the answer by Winther](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900048/66081)), but maybe these notes will help someone in following the argument and forming their own opinion.

[The Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) is the conjecture that the Riemann zeta function has its zeros only at the negative even integers ("trivial zeros") and the complex numbers $\frac12 + i t$ for real $t$.

The function
$$
\Xi(t) := \xi(\tfrac12 + i t),
\quad
\xi(s) := \tfrac{s(s-1)}{2} \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(\tfrac{s}{2}) \zeta(s)
,
$$
serves as a proxy to the $\zeta$-function, because as it says [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Xi-Function.html),

- the zeros of $\xi$ are all located on the strip $(0,1) + i \mathbb{R}$,
- for real $t$, one has: $\Xi(t) = 0$ iff $\zeta(\frac12 + i t) = 0$,
- $\Xi(t)$ is real for real $t$.

In particular, $\Xi$ does not share the trivial zeros with $\zeta$. 
Hence,
$$ \label{e:RH} \tag{RH}
\Xi(t) = 0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
t \in \mathbb{R}
$$
is what the author sets out to prove (p.1).

To do that, the author introduces the family of functions 
$$
[0, \tfrac\pi2] \to \mathbb{C},
\quad
x \mapsto v_\Psi(x, t),
$$
parameterized by a scalar $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and a function $\Psi : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$
as
$$
v_\Psi(x, t) 
:=
\int_0^\infty \cos( t (y + \cos(x)) ) \Psi(y) \, dy
.
$$

He observes (p.4) that
for a particular choice of $\Psi$,
there holds
$$ \label{e:xiv} \tag{1}
\Xi(t) = \Xi(0) \, v_\Psi(\tfrac\pi2, t)
\quad
\forall t \in \mathbb{C}
.
$$

The key argument is then this:
$$ \label{e:key} \tag{2}
\text{If $t \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $v_\Psi(\tfrac\pi2, t) = 0$ then $t^2$ is real.}
$$

Note that in that case, either

- $t \in i \mathbb{R}$, which is incompatible with \eqref{e:xiv} because $\Xi(t) \neq 0$ for such $t$ (see above), or
- $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

So: \eqref{e:xiv}-\eqref{e:key} imply \eqref{e:RH}.

---

The particular function $\Psi$ for which \eqref{e:xiv} holds
is readily available (apparently; I'm no expert and would welcome a reference, but I have "verified" numerically).
Since 
$$
\Xi(t) = \int_0^\infty \cos(t y) 2 \Phi(y) \,dy
,
$$
where
$$
\Phi(y) = 
2 \pi e^{\frac52 y} \sum_{n \geq 1} 
(2 \pi e^{2 y} n^2 - 3)
n^2
e^{-n^2 \pi e^{2 y}}
,
$$
the choice
$$
\Psi := 2 / \Xi(0) \, \Phi 
$$
gives \eqref{e:xiv}.

To observe is

- the super-exponential decay of $\Psi(y)$ as $y \to \infty$ due to the double exponential in the sum,
- measurability of $\Psi$,
- $\Psi \geq 0$, and
- $\int_0^\infty \Psi(y) \,dy = 1$.

---

It remains to discuss the key argument \eqref{e:key}.
The author's strategy is to prove this for any function $\Psi$ that satisfies the above four observations; the particular shape of $\Psi$ is therefore irrelevant for this argument. This is the subject of Lemma 3 (p.3):

Suppose $t \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that
$$
v_\Psi(\tfrac\pi2, t) = 0.
$$

Fix this $t$. To show: $t^2$ is real.

The idea is to show that the function
$$
f :
[0, \tfrac\pi2] \to \mathbb{C},
\quad
x \mapsto v_\Psi(x, t)
$$

- satisfies a [Sturm--Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) eigenvalue problem with eigenvalue $t^2$, and
- apply a classical result that says that the eigenvalue is necessarily real.

The Sturm--Liouville eigenvalue problem is
$$
\text{SL}_f := (f' / r)' + ( t^2 p + q ) f = 0 \text{  on  } (0, \tfrac\pi2),
\quad
f'(0) = 0,
\quad
f(\tfrac\pi2) = 0
,
$$
where
$$
r = p = \sin
\quad\text{and}\quad
q = 0
.
$$

Note that our $f$ is (complex-valued but) $C^2$ due to the good integrability of $\Psi$.

Some elementary manipulations show that the eigenvalue problem is indeed satisfied, including the boundary conditions (the one at $\frac\pi2$ by assumption).

The author cites Theorem 8.3.1 in [F.V. Atkinson, Discrete and Continuous Boundary Problems. Academic Press, New York, London,
1964] which says that under those conditions, the eigenvalue $t^2$ is real (the Sturm--Liouville operator is self-adjoint, after all).
The theorem is quoted almost verbatim in the manuscript.

Sidenote:
Testing the eigenvalue problem with $\bar{f}$ and integrating would immediately show that $t^2$ is real, but the theorem also gives the summability $\sum_{t \in \Xi^{-1}(0)} |t|^{-1-\epsilon} < \infty$ of the countably many zeros of $\Xi$.

---

**Edit**: The answer by Winther points to where the problem could be. Indeed,
$$
f'(x) = t \sin(x) \int_0^\infty \sin(t(y + \cos(x))) \Psi(y) \, dy
$$
behaves like $f' \propto \sin$ at $x = 0$, so the following computation is justified (all terms are finite; upper boundary term is zero):
$$
0 =
\int_0^{\frac\pi2}
\text{SL}_f \, \bar{f}
=
 - \frac{f'(0^+)}{\sin(0^+)} \bar{f}(0^+)  
+
\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \{ -r^{-1}|f'|^2 + t^2 p |f|^2\}
.
$$
If the boundary term was zero (or just real), we could conclude that $t^2$ is real.
However:
$$
\frac{f'(0^+)}{\sin(0^+)} \bar{f}(0^+) = t \times (\text{a real nonzero constant})
$$
could be complex,
so $t^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ cannot be concluded.

Comment: Did you examine the claim by les-mathematiques.net user YvesM, mentioned in the comments on main, to have found errors, stating that "Condition 5,b does not imply v(1)=0 and the differential equation on v is wrong" (I am translating)?

Comment: OMG it is true?!?!?!?

Comment: Note that there are two versions of the paper [v1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01555v1.pdf) and [v2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01555v2.pdf). The "$v(1) = 0$" objection mentioned by Did refers to the first version. The same claim for the second version is that $v(\pi/2) = 0$. However this is by assumption so I don't think the error (and there has to be an error somewhere) is there.

Comment: @Winther: thanks for clarifying this

Comment: @Winther my observertion was that he does not use $\zeta(s)$ has an Euler product anywhere, so his argument has to be flawed (because there are counter-examples with similar $\Xi(t)$ but having no Euler product  and  some zeros off the critical line)

Comment: @user1952009 Is this a simple matter of the author failing to mentioning that $\zeta (s)$ has an Euler product anywhere, or is the flaw deeper than that?

Comment: What is the meaning of $f' \propto \sin$ ? Is this a common notation?

Comment: @mixedmath: [prop(ortional )to](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328925/what-does-propto-mean)

Comment: @ForeverMozart The point is that the argument the OP gives would, if correct, apply to functions which we know *don't* satisfy the (analogue of the) Riemann hypothesis. It's more than just not mentioning the Euler product; the point is that the proof has to rely on *some* property of the $\zeta$ function which fails for these "near-$\zeta$" functions.

Comment: Hello, I have a question regarding the function $v_\Psi$: As you pointed out reality of the eigenvalues can not be concluded. However I'm wondering if there must be at all eigenvalues $t_n$ for which $v_\Psi(\pi/2,t_n)=0$. For example $\Psi(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \, e^{-y^2}$ leads to $v_\Psi(\pi/2,t)=e^{-t^2/4}$ which doesn't have any roots...